# Pimcore and Dependency Injection

Tags: pimcore, php-di

I want to use Dependency Injection in Pimcore. Luckily this is possible out of the box since Pimcore 4.x.

But I must admit that I can't get it to work. I read those sites: [DI](https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Dependency_Injection.html), [DI](https://www.pimcore.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22282310), [DI](https://www.pimcore.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22282304)

as well as the documentation of php-di since Pimcore is using it.

Now I have a plugin, a simple search, that I want to inject into one of my controller.

The plugins structure looks like this:

```
plugins
  - MyPlugin
    - lib
      - MyPlugin
        - Models
          Search.php
    - static
    - plugin.xml
```

I want to inject the class inside `Search.php` into my controller.

```
# plugins/MyPlugin/lib/MyPlugin/Models/Search.php
class MyPlugin_Models_Search
```

The class itself has no namespace, but has one defined in plugin.xml

```
# plugins/MyPlugin/plugin.xml
<pluginNamespace>MyPlugin</pluginNamespace>
```

I copied the `di.example.php` to `website/config/di.php` and it is called, I veryfied that.

My definitions look like this:

```
# website/config/di.php
<?php

return [
  'MyPlugin' => DI\object()->property('myPlugin', DI\get('MyPlugin_Models_Search')),
  # 'myPlugin' => \DI\object()->constructor(DI\get('MyPlugin_Models_Search'))
  # 'myPlugin' => new MyPlugin_Models_Search() // crashes everything :)
  # 'MyPlugin_Models_Search' => new MyPlugin_Models_Search()
  # many more ...
];
```

My controller:

```
# website/controllers/FooController.php
<?php

use Website\Controller\Action;

class FooController extends Action
{

  public $myPlugin;

  # this won't work: Declaration of FooController::__construct() must be
  # compatible with Zend_Controller_Action_Interface::__construct(
  # Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_
  # Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = Array)
  public function __construct($plugin) {

    $this->myPlugin = $plugin;

  }

  public function FooAction() { var_dump($this->myPlugin); }

}
```

I even tried to set the definition directly in `pimcore/lib/Pimcore.php` in `function getDiContainer()` but no success.

Any ideas? Thanks you and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Plugin Developer Guide](https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Extending_Pimcore/Plugin_Developers_Guide/Plugin_Anatomy.html):

```
 <!-- include paths relative to plugin-directory -->
<pluginIncludePaths>
<path>/ExtensionExample/path1</path>
<path>/ExtensionExample/path2</path>
</pluginIncludePaths>
<!-- namespaces to register with autoloader-->
<pluginNamespaces>
<namespace>ExtensionExample</namespace>
<namespace>Resource</namespace>
</pluginNamespaces>
```

So you can add your Plugin Namespace to the Autoloader via config, no need to code this at your own.

Comment: btw: it was never necessary to modify DI files for installing plugins.

Comment: You can have a look at some other public plugins like "Member" https://github.com/pimcore-extensions/member/blob/master/plugin.xml